# Repeat 3000 times a sequence of characters "OW HW1 HW2" in a column

Tags: bash

I would like to have the following sequence:
OW
HW1
HW2
being repeated in an output file 3000 times such as:

```
OW
HW1
HW2
.
.
.
OW
HW1
HW2
```

I believe I can, by using bash, set the OW, HW1 and HW2 as independent variable and then make a do loop 3000 times and print the values in the output file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If use `for` `in` cycle:

```
for i in $(seq 1 3000) ; do echo -e "OW\nHW1\nHW2"; done
```

or use echo 3x

```
for i in $(seq 1 3000) ; do echo OW; echo HW1; echo HW2; done
```

Comment: This is great, but then how do I print this sequence 3000 times in the file?

Comment: Use redirection: `for i in $(seq 1 3000) ; do echo -e "OW\nHW1\nHW2" >>file.txt ; done`

Comment: I like this.  Most clear answer in my opinion.  OOC, is `seq 3000` the same as `seq 1 3000`?

Answer (score 13):

You can use this `printf` trick with a zero-length string specifier `%.0s` and brace expansion:

```
printf '%.0sOW\nHW1\nHW2\n' {1..3000} > newfile
```

Comment: super this works just perfect!!!!

Comment: This is a good (brief) solution for small inputs, but very inefficient when the number of repetitions is large. Better to use awk in that case, e.g. `awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=3000;i++)print"OW\nHW1\nHW2"}'>file`

Comment: @user000001 So it's the right tool for the job in this post...

Answer (score 7):

It can be easily done with Perl:

```
perl -e'print "OW\n\HW1\nHW2\n"x3000'
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use `yes` and `head` to generate this sequence 3000 times.

```
yes $'OW\nHW1\nHW2' | head -9000
```

Here you need the 9000 because you have 3 lines and you want those 3 lines 3000 times.

Answer (score 3):

If your shell offers "brace expansion", try

```
echo $'\nOW\nHW1\nHW2\n'{1..3000}$'\n' | grep -Ev "^( |[0-9])*$"
OW
HW1
HW2
OW
HW1
HW2
OW
HW1
HW2
.
.
.
```

and redirect to a file if happy with the result.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a while loop like here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html

An example:

```
COUNTER=0; while [ $COUNTER -lt 3 ]; do echo "$COUNTER" && COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1)); done
```

Don't forget to reset the COUNTER every time you want to run this.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 solution

```
python3 -c 'print("OW\nHW1\nHW2\n"*3000, end="")'
```